# Probability of 3 errors in a Book of 200 pages?

Tags: combinatorics

The probability that i make an error/typo while writing a page is $0.02\%$. For a book of 200 pages, what is the probability that i have at most 3 pages with an error ?

My first thought was that it is simply $0.98^{197}$. I write 197 pages without making an error however that does not take into account if i make only one error or two or none.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)?

Comment: Assuming each page containing an error or not is independent of one another, an answer of $0.98^{197}$ is going to be the answer of what the probability is that *very specifically* the first $197$ pages you make no error and the final three pages we don't care about, they might or might not have errors.  This doesn't account for cases where one or more of the first $197$ pages has an error such as the twentieth page containing an error and no other pages having errors.

Comment: Yes! But i was not sure if i understood it correctly. In my case would X = 4 ? My first equation would be ${200\choose 0} *0.02^0 * 0.98^{200} $ and then subtract everything up until ${200\choose 3} *0.02^3 * 0.98^{197} $ from 1 but wouldn't this be the probability of writing 4 books with making at most 3 errors or am i wrong? Again i am a bit confused about the meaning ob the binomial distribution but if i should use it then i have the solution to it.

Comment: No, we are still talking about a single book.  And no, we are not subtracting this away from $1$ in this particular problem.  We hadn't talked about what $X$ is yet, but if we let $X$ be the random variable counting the total number of pages with errors, we are talking about $Pr(X\leq 3)$ which you should know is equal to $Pr(X=0)+Pr(X=1)+Pr(X=2)+Pr(X=3)$.  That is, the probability that our book has zero errors *or* our book (*the same book*) having one error *or* etc...

Comment: Thanks you helped me out a lot !